# Parsing discussion from gitter

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing

I would like to copy some discussion from gitter. E.g. this one [2015/08/19 archive](https://gitter.im/numenta/public/archives/2015/08/19). The problem is that simple ctrl+a and ctrl+c does not copy user names nor dates. Those information are included in the source code of the page. What is the most simple way of doing this? I prefer minimum working examples in python (with little explanation of code). Format could be e.g.:

```
(DATE) USERNAME: MESSAGE
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very straight-forward when using the `requests` library and `beautifulsoup4` (both PIP installable under those same names).

**gitter.py**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


markup_str = requests.get("https://gitter.im/numenta/public/archives/2015/08/19").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup_str, 'html.parser')

chat_container = soup.find(id='chat-container')
chat_items = chat_container.find_all(class_='chat-item')

for chat_item in chat_items:
    msg = chat_item.find(class_='chat-item__text').get_text().strip()
    poster = chat_item.find(class_='chat-item__from').get_text().strip()
    posted_at = chat_item.find(class_='chat-item__time').get_text().strip()
    print "({}) {}: {}".format(posted_at, poster, msg)
```

output when run:

```
(Aug 19 00:09) rhyolight: I just released NuPIC 0.2.7
(Aug 19 00:09) rhyolight: waiting on the build to publish binaries
(Aug 19 00:09) rhyolight: https://github.com/numenta/nupic/releases/tag/0.2.7
(Aug 19 01:48) rhyolight: https://travis-ci.org/numenta/nupic/builds/76213223
[...snip...]
```

We're basically just iterating over all of the elements with a class of `chat-item` in the `#chat-container` parent. For each of them we read `chat-item__text`, `chat-item__from`, and `chat-item__time`.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked like a charm. I've noticed that there are no elements which have pure `class='chat-item'` attribute. So using `class_='chat-item'` does regexp search and first finds those elements containing `model-id` e.g. `<div class="chat-item model-id-55d3c9239c0eaccb36ae2e8e burstStart read ">` and further `chat_item.find` does also regexp search over elements nested under `<div class="chat-item model-id-55d3c9239c0eaccb36ae2e8e burstStart read ">` am I right? Thank you

Comment: @WakanTanka Good question! Looking at the [source for bs4](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1656), by the time it is doing matching the `class` attribute has already been split into a list of individual classes that are then checked individually. No regex needed!

Comment: Well, not for the searching at least. They do use the regex `\s+` to split multi value markup attribute values into a list of values.

Comment: I was primary pointing to fact that first calling to `chat_item.find` return the parent and second calling to `chat_item.find` return the children of the parent (first call)